# Magento : sending wrong order total to paypal, calculating total without tax applied on each product

Tags: magento, paypal

Magento displaying correct result in cart but when I click for making payment then it shows wrong total result on paypal. Its showing total of item price without calculating tax for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the country in Admin> System> General and in shipping setting. 
Match with merchant paypal country and check again.